# Rxjs observable is subscribed twice

Tags: reactjs, rxjs, observable, reactive-programming, reactive

I am starting with rxjs library, trying to make requests to an API REST. The problem i got i that the code inside the `subscribe` is executed two times but is just called once

The `observable` method, creates an `observable` from a `promise`

```
post(url, body): Observable<Response> {
    return from(fetch(url, {
       method: 'POST',
       body: JSON.stringify(body),
       headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
       }
     }))
 }
```

And then, the code i am using to read the value of the stream is: (I have checked and it is only called once)

```
doLogin(){
    var creds={
        "email":"user@gmail.com",
        "password":"user"
    }
    var stream$ =this.httpService.post("http://localhost:8080/api/login",creds)
    stream$.subscribe(x=>console.log(x))
}
```

The result that i see in the navigator console is 2 `console.log()` with the result of the fetch response

Comment: you can put a `console.log` after `var stream$`, this way you know if your `doLogin` is called twice or not.

Comment: I ve done it, the method `doLogin` is only executed once

Answer (score 0):

I think inside a subscribe function what actually happening is that, you define what to do when you receive a new value from the stream. That means subscribe is not actually being executed twice, rather it is receiving a value twice.

Comment: That could be the reason, i have tested printing a timestamp in the console log and the fist log is done 1 milisecond before the second one. Do you know how the first method could be sending two values in the stream?